# Pandas Storing df to csv in BytesIO

Tags: python, pandas, io

I want to store the output of `df` to `csv` in Memory Object of `BytesIo()` (Not `StringIO`) and then zip it and here is my attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io
import zipfile
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
s_buf = io.BytesIO()
df.to_csv(s_buf)
s_buf.seek(0)
localfile= io.BytesIO()
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(localfile, mode="w",compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
zf.writestr(localfile, s_buf.read())
zf.close()
with open("D:/my_zip.zip", "wb") as f: # use `wb` mode
    f.write(zf.getvalue())
```

Comment: what is the result of this code? it doesn't work??

Comment: `df.to_csv(s_buf)` => `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this would be helpful:-

```
import gzip
from io import BytesIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))
b_buf = BytesIO()
with gzip.open(b_buf, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(df.to_csv().encode())
b_buf.seek(0)
with open("my_zip.zip", "wb") as f:
    f.write(b_buf.getvalue())
```